# How to install NVM permanently on macos Catalina?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, macos, terminal

I did the installing part of nvm properly and put the path to the bash_profile also. On the same terminal it showed me that nvm is working. After that i closed my terminal and run "nvm" it shows that "zsh: command not found: nvm". I need a solution for this.

Answer (score 6):

first confirm if there is ~/.bash_profile and ~/.zshrc file, if not exist, run in order:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
touch ~/.zshrc
```

then use below to install nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

after installed, to add nvm dir to your env, run `open ~/.bash_profile`, add below two lines into the .bash_profile file:

```
source "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.nvm
```

close and reopen your terminal and run `nvm -v` to check if it works

NOTE: if it still not works, you may have to copy and run below command manually in terminal

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 3):

You are adding the path to bash profile which is for bash terminal. Starting with MacOS 10.15 the default terminal is `zsh`. Either add the path to the `~/.zshrc` or inside the same file put the following lines:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

Don't forget to restart your terminal.